# PHP: generate all possible alphanumeric combinations of a string

Tags: php, string

**Context:** I have a function where I set the string's length as a parameter, let's say 8. That function generates a string from AAAAAAAA to ZZZZZZZZ. It actually generates 1 combination, stores it in a txt file, reloads the webpage, then tries the next combination: AAAAAAAA --> refresh --> AAAAAAAB --> refresh --> ... --> ZZZZZZZY ---> refresh --> ZZZZZZZZZ

**The code:** It looks pretty much like this (I removed all the un-necessary parts for your conveniance)

```
function combinations($size) {
    $string = str_repeat('a',$size);
    $endLoopTest = str_repeat('z',$size);
    $endLoopTest++;
    while ($string != $endLoopTest) {
        echo $string++,PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**The problem:** It works fine for chars from A to Z, but I would like to consider numeric chars as well (0 to 9). The "$string++" trick is very conveniant in PHP as I can increment strings. Now that I want to add numeric chars as well, I'd need to completely rewrite this function's logic.

**Precisions:** I still want to generate 1 string at a time --> refresh the page --> "increment" the previous string --> generate the new string --> refresh --> etc

Comment: Do you mean include the numbers in the alphabetical sequence: 0000-ZZZZ or just do the same thing but with numbers: 0000-9999?

Comment: 0000-ZZZZ obviously.

Comment: [Rude](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: I did not mean to be rude. The level of difficulty is way different between "0000-ZZZZ" and "0000-9999", I would not ask otherwise. I mean, the second one, someone that just started learning PHP could do it, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We have a wide range of different users with varying levels of expertise. Please always try to be as specific in your question as possible, so as to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve/the problem you are experiencing is.

Comment: You have to rewrite the logic in that case..

Comment: Seems like you either want a unique id, or a bruteforce program, but whatever. You could keep a few counters, which you simply increase. then use `ord()` and `chr()` to convert it back to ascii characters.

Comment: "Now that I want to add numeric chars as well [...]" I believe this was specific enough and not ambiguous about "00-ZZ" and "00-99". Anyways, thank you for your time. This question got downvoted 4 times already (for reasons I don't even understand), so It will go un-noticed now. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be as elegant as you want... but it shows a way to do what you want -- maybe it will teach you something new.

```
function increasePosition(&$cString, $nPosition) {
    //get the char of the current position
    $cChar = substr($cString, $nPosition - 1, 1);

    //convert to the ascii value (and add one)
    $nChar = ord($cChar) + 1;

    if ($nChar == 58) {
        $nChar = 97; //one past 9, go to a
    }

    if ($nChar == 123) {
        $nChar = 48; //one past z, go to 0
        //we hit z, so increase the next space to the left
        increasePosition($cString, $nPosition - 1);
    }

    //replace the expected position with the new character
    $cString[$nPosition - 1] = chr($nChar);
}

function myCombinations($nSize) {
    //init to 0 repeating.
    $cString = str_repeat('0', $nSize);
    //move the last character 'back' one, so that 0 repeating will be the first item.
    $cString[$nSize - 1] = '/';
    //when to stop.
    $cEnd = str_repeat('z', $nSize);

    while ($cString != $cEnd) {
        increasePosition($cString, $nSize);
        print($cString . " ");
    }
}

myCombinations(2);
```

Comment: This could be condensed some. For example $cChar is not needed... so you could combine that line with the following line. However I left it more verbose so that you could add debug messages easier.

Comment: Aah, I was just about to post this aswell (almost hit send), good solution.