# Generating all 6 character alphanumeric combinations (upper and lower case)

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations

I am trying to figure out a way to generate a list of every possible 6 character alphanumber string where upper and lower case letters are treated as unique letters. Using the following functions we can generate the strings using lowercase letters and numbers:

```php
function increasePosition(&$cString, $nPosition) {
    //get the char of the current position
    $cChar = substr($cString, $nPosition - 1, 1);

    //convert to the ascii value (and add one)
    $nChar = ord($cChar) + 1;

    if ($nChar == 58) {
        $nChar = 97; //one past 9, go to a
    }

    if ($nChar == 123) {
        $nChar = 48; //one past z, go to 0
        //we hit z, so increase the next space to the left
        increasePosition($cString, $nPosition - 1);
    }

    //replace the expected position with the new character
    $cString[$nPosition - 1] = chr($nChar);
}

function myCombinations($nSize) {
    //init to 0 repeating.
    $cString = str_repeat('0', $nSize);
    //move the last character 'back' one, so that 0 repeating will be the first item.
    $cString[$nSize - 1] = '/';
    //when to stop.
    $cEnd = str_repeat('z', $nSize);

    while ($cString != $cEnd) {
        increasePosition($cString, $nSize);
        print($cString . " ");
    }
}

myCombinations(2);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32524299/1538275)

However, this doesn't take into account uppercase letters. Is it possible to use both upper and lower case letters in this sort of algorithm in PHP?

Comment: just add the ascii code range for upper case

Comment: `(26+26+10)^6 ` Thats a lot of data

Comment: @Steve Yes it is, these will be stored as a pool of filenames to grab from.

Comment: you need half a billion filenames? Wow

Comment: auto-increment ids's or one of the unique functions would be easier.

Comment: @Dagon yes it would be easier, but these filenames are being used as URLs and we wanted to keep them as short as possible so we use letters as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add a small block to take care of upper case characters:

```
<?php

function increasePosition(&$cString, $nPosition) {
    //get the char of the current position
    $cChar = substr($cString, $nPosition - 1, 1);

    //convert to the ascii value (and add one)
    $nChar = ord($cChar) + 1;

    if ($nChar == 58) {
        $nChar = 65; //one past 9, go to A
    }

    if ($nChar == 91) {
        $nChar = 97; //one past Z, go to a
    }


    if ($nChar == 123) {
        $nChar = 48; //one past z, go to 0
        //we hit z, so increase the next space to the left
        increasePosition($cString, $nPosition - 1);
    }

    //replace the expected position with the new character
    $cString[$nPosition - 1] = chr($nChar);
}

function myCombinations($nSize) {
    //init to 0 repeating.
    $cString = str_repeat('0', $nSize);
    //move the last character 'back' one, so that 0 repeating will be the first item.
    $cString[$nSize - 1] = '/';
    //when to stop.
    $cEnd = str_repeat('z', $nSize);

    while ($cString != $cEnd) {
        increasePosition($cString, $nSize);
        print($cString . " ");
    }
}

myCombinations(6);
```